# Mac Terminal Crashes After I input command

Tags: macos, terminal

Everytime I open my terminal and try to type anything i get the following error:

```
Process:               Terminal [6453]
Path:                  /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal
Identifier:            com.apple.Terminal
Version:               2.5.3 (343.7)
Build Info:            Terminal-343007000000000~1
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Terminal [6453]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-08-23 09:29:35.004 -0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.10.5 (14F27)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        0A060F19-F5B3-65E6-9027-C5A87C187A3B

Sleep/Wake UUID:       2B3B6D3A-F8F0-4AE8-9E8C-2BB283574708

Time Awake Since Boot: 120000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       4700 seconds

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000003e

VM Regions Near 0x3e:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000109ba7000-0000000109c57000 [  704K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8eecf334 parseXML + 8724
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8ee5a21e CFXMLParserParse + 302
2   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff811f2453 IBXDecoderLoad + 252
3   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff811f20ad loadNib + 218
4   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff811f1f85 CreateMenuFromNib + 75
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff811f1c59 GetStandardMenu + 121
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff811f0392 AppleMenuHandler(OpaqueEventHandlerCallRef*, OpaqueEventRef*, void*) + 486
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff811a0b6c DispatchEventToHandlers(EventTargetRec*, OpaqueEventRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 1260
8   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8119ffae SendEventToEventTargetInternal(OpaqueEventRef*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, HandlerCallRec*) + 386
9   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8119fe22 SendEventToEventTargetWithOptions + 43
10  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff811ecaec SendMenuPopulate(MenuData*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, unsigned int, double, unsigned int, OpaqueEventRef*, unsigned char*) + 293
11  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff811ec8b1 PopulateMenu(MenuData*, OpaqueEventTargetRef*, CheckMenuData*, unsigned int, double) + 74
12  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff811ebf6c Check1MenuForKeyEvent(MenuData*, CheckMenuData*) + 224
13  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff811eb824 CheckMenusForKeyEvent(MenuData*, CheckMenuData*) + 880
14  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff811eb429 _IsMenuKeyEvent(MenuData*, OpaqueEventRef*, unsigned int, MenuData**, unsigned short*) + 713
15  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff811eb120 IsMenuKeyEvent + 110
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88e86996 +[NSCarbonMenuImpl _menuItemWithKeyEquivalentMatchingEventRef:inMenu:] + 331
17  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88e8671a _NSFindMenuItemMatchingCommandKeyEvent + 300
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88da4c21 _NSHandleCarbonMenuEvent + 86
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88cdbbfd _DPSNextEvent + 1828
20  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88cdae58 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88cd0af3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88c4d244 NSApplicationMain + 1832
23  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff83d0e5c9 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff82b82232 kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff8b9c7a6a _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:: com.apple.terminal.low-disk-space-handler
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff82b8221a kevent + 10
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ad94e92 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88be105a _pthread_body + 131
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88be0fd7 _pthread_start + 176
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88bde3ed thread_start + 13

Thread 3:: com.apple.terminal.sigchld-handler
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff82b82682 read + 10
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ad94e92 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88be105a _pthread_body + 131
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88be0fd7 _pthread_start + 176
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88bde3ed thread_start + 13

Thread 4:: com.apple.terminal.tty-io
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff82b813fa __select + 10
1   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8ad94e92 __NSThread__main__ + 1345
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88be105a _pthread_body + 131
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88be0fd7 _pthread_start + 176
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88bde3ed thread_start + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff82b7c4de mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff82b7b64f mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8edf6eb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8edf637b __CFRunLoopRun + 1371
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8edf5bd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff88da356b _NSEventThread + 137
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88be105a _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88be0fd7 _pthread_start + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88bde3ed thread_start + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff82b8194a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88bde3dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff82b8194a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88bde3dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff82b8194a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88bde3dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff82b8194a __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff88bde3dd start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000001  rbx: 0x0000000000000001  rcx: 0x000000000000003e  rdx: 0x00006000000ec080
  rdi: 0x00007fa491c05fb0  rsi: 0x0000000000000002  rbp: 0x00007fff560576c0  rsp: 0x00007fff560574a0
   r8: 0x00000000ffffffff   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x00007fa492845300  r11: 0x00007fff560572f3
  r12: 0x00007fa491c05fa0  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x00007fa491c05fb0  r15: 0x00007fff560574f6
  rip: 0x00007fff8eecf334  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x000000000000003e

Logical CPU:     1
Error Code:      0x00000006
Trap Number:     14
```

Comment: Look at this https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3734077?start=0 that's the first result when you google EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) and and there's some steps  at the bottom that you can follow ```Be sure your Mac is shut down.
Press the power button. 
Immediately after you hear the startup tone, hold the Shift key. The Shift key should be held as soon as possible after the startup tone, but not before the tone.
Release the Shift key when you see the gray Apple icon and the progress indicator (looks like a spinning gear).```

Comment: @stresscool - then what? Safe mode won't fix it.

Comment: @daniel-pereira The idea is to check if you still have the problem this way, then try to remember what's the latest thing you added or changed.

Comment: The link you provided was for a graphics crash - totally unrelated. First thing I'd do is delete the saved state at ~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Terminal.savedState & see what happens.

Comment: @Tetsujin I can't seem to find the Path. There is no "Saved Application State" on my Library Folder. I also can't search because my finder crashes if I try to. I will try to do stresscool suggestion

Comment: User Library, not system ~/Lib... not /Lib... but if the Finder crashes too, then your problems are deeper, try http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243290/troubleshooting-mac-issues for starters. It includes a safe boot, to rebuild caches, but is not the first step.